# Публичный API для получения сегодняшней даты

Tags: java, дата

Есть ли сервис, который предоставляет сегодняшнюю дату с API, да еще и безвозмездно?

Comment: А чем вас System.currentTimeMillis() не устраивает?

Comment: @rjhdby много чем, вопрос о другом.
Один из пунктов, на устройстве дату всегда можно поменять

Comment: https://www.ntp-servers.net/rules.html - судя по описанию у них все бесплатно, но я не тестировал. http://moskovskoe.vremja.org/ - тут просто время, надо самому писать парсер. Впрочем - только для даты, ничего сложного, думаю)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now

Найдено в ответе на [аналогичный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549185/is-there-a-time-server-that-offers-an-api-that-i-can-grab-the-current-eastern-ti) на EN.SE.
Ну и в [другом вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240530/free-rest-api-to-get-current-time-as-string-timezone-irrelevant) тоже можно найти несколько различных ссылок.

Answer (score 1):

Можно получить например вот здесь:     http://www.timeanddate.com/

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/88260)

Comment: @Denis аккуратнее. Автор спрашивал ссылку на сервис - и она предоставлена. Возможно, вопрос не очень качественный - но про ответ такого сказать нельзя.

Comment: @PavelMayorov вы правы, спасибо, буду внимательней.